# Abrir una pestaña en blanco en Firefox

Tags: firefox

Ya googlee y no hallé nada....

Quiero en firefox abrir una nueva pestaña con el contenido totalmente en blanco.

Esto en Chrome se logra mediante

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

y escribiendo en la barra de navegación la ruta:

```
about:blank
```

pero en firefox me sale una página de error con una imágen

[image: página de error con un oso feo y malencarado de color azul]

Por si fuera relevante tengo firefox versión 88.0 en Windows

Comment: Intenta configurar el inicio de Firefox con una página en blanco desde los ajustes, quizá ahí te muestre la url en blanco que quieres.

Comment: Tal como te comentan, Firefox tiene una opción en la que indicas qué hacer al abrir una nueva pestaña, allí seleccionas *página en blanco*. A partir de ese momento, cada vez que uses el acceso directo de pestaña nueva (`ctrl+t`), se abrirá una página en blanco en una nueva pestaña. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Vas al menú de firefox, editar, inicio y las primeras opciones te da la posibilidad de abrir las pestañas de firefox en blanco.

Comment: no me sale esa opción en el menú editar

Comment: Editar, preferencias, inicio. En las primeras opciones puedes configurar como quieres que se te abran las paginas nuevas.

Comment: Sigue sin aparecer esa opción para mí, podrías agregar capturas o algo?

Comment: Igual no tienes la barra de menús. Sino es así no lo comprendo. Si no tienes la barra de menú, dale click al botón derecho del ratón a la parte negra de arriba del navegador y activa la barra de menús. Si tienes la barra de menú y no te sale la opcion de editar en el menú, ya no puedo ayudarte.

Comment: Tengo la barra de menú, pero tal vez sea diferente porque mi navegador está en inglés. Podrías poner una captura o algo para ver si tiene un hotkey?

Comment: Las capturas no atrapan los submenus. No te lo puedo mostrar con captura. Pero sera edit y options o preference. No se como es en ingles el menu de firefox, te tocara buscar traducciones. Suerte

Comment: yo si pude tomar captura de los submenús, te recomiendo intentarlo de nuevo o cambiar de programa https://javapro.org/lenguajes-de-maquetado/convertir-de-html4-a-html5-rapido/